# Strongly Typed Dictionary Class in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I'm trying to create a strongly-typed Dictionary class in VB.NET.  I'm tired of typing

```
Dim people as Dictionary(Of String, Person)
```

and want to make a PersonDictionary class so I can say

```
Dim people as PersonDictionary
```

My reference material says to create a new class that inherits the DictionaryBase class. Then override the Add, Remove, and Item Sub/Properties.

It seems like a pretty common pattern, is there an easier way?

Thanks

Comment: What is difficult on overriding these methods with f.e. mybase.add(person)?

Comment: I suppose it's not THAT difficult, just wondering if there's a better way.  It looks like I also have to override the keys property. Shouldn't I get that for free?

Comment: You are getting that for free if you use the generic type Dictionary(Of String, Person). I don't see why you need to inherit from.

Comment: `Imports` statement can be used to give an alias to an existing type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could do this:

```
Public Class PersonDictionary
    Inherits Dictionary(Of String, Person)

End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

```
imports MyDictionary = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of string, string)

public module MyModule
    Sub Main()
        dim myData as New MyDictionary
        mydata.Add("hello", "world")
        Console.WriteLine(mydata.Keys.Count)

        mydata.Add("hello2", "world2")
        Console.WriteLine(mydata.Keys.Count)

    End Sub
end module
```